# The existence of minimizer.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given $\|\cdot\|$ to be a norm over space $M$ and $(x(t))\subset M$ is a sequence of points for any $t\geq0$.

I know the function $t\to \|x(t)\|$ is *continuous* and *strictly decreasing* w.r.t. $t$. Also, $\lim_{t\to\infty}\|(x(t))\|=c>0$

My question: can we prove that the existence of minimizer
$$
x(t_0):=\operatorname{argmin}_{t\geq 0}\|x(t)-x_0\|
$$
where $x_0\in M$.

Also, can we show that the minimizer is unique?

Comment: @UmbertoP. $x(t_0)$ is a point. I used the symbol $argmin$.

Comment: What happens if $x(t) = \frac{1}{2t} x_0$ for $ t \ge 1$ and $x(t) = (2-t) x_0$ for $0 \le t < 1$?

Comment: @Umberto Oh sorry I forgot an assumption

Comment: What happens if $x(t) = (1 + \frac 1t) x_0$ for $t \ge 1$ and $x(t) = (3-t)x_0$ for $0 \le t <1$?

Comment: Or (more simply) $x(t) = (1+e^{-t})x_0$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I see. You concern the problem at tail. You are right. Let me try to reform my problem. In my problem I have a good reason to assume that as $t\to \infty$, $\|x(t)-x_0\|$ will become large. (There are too much background I need to give if I want to state this properties clearly)