# If there is a minimizer, can I show the function is quasi-convex

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

There are some early discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511187/the-existence-of-minimizer?noredirect=1#comment3077898_1511187). (Thanks for @Umberto for his clear and nice comment!)

Now I reformed my problem. Please have a look.

Given $\|\cdot\|$ to be a norm over space $M$ and $(x(t))\subset M$ is a sequence of points for any $t\geq0$.

I know the function $t\to \|x(t)\|$ is *convex* and *strictly decreasing* w.r.t. $t$. Also, $\lim_{t\to\infty}\|(x(t))\|=c>0$.

I also know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x(t)-x_0\|=c'>\|x(t')-x_0\|$ where $x_0$ is a point in $M$ and $t'>0$ is finite. i.e., the minimizer of below problem can not happen as $t\to\infty$.

Moreover, I have, there exists a point $x_a$ so that the function $t\to \|x(t)-x_a\|$ is strictly increasing.

My question:

1. can I show the uniqueness and existence of minimizer $x(t_0)$?
   $$
   x(t_0):=\operatorname{argmin}_{t\geq 0}\|x(t)-x_0\|
   $$
2. can I show that function $t\to \|x(t)-x_0\|$ is [quasi-convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function)?

Comment: Is $M$ a Hilbert space? Or, at least, reflexive?

Comment: @gerw yes. You can take $M$ is $L_2$ space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By your assumptions, there exist $M > 0$, such that the minimizing $t$ is between $0$ and $M$. Hence, there exists a sequence $\{t_n\} \subset [0,M]$ with 
   $$\|x(t_n) - x_0\| \to \inf_{t \ge 0} \| x(t) - x_0 \|.$$
   W.l.o.g., the sequence $\{t_n\}$ converges to some $\bar t$. Since $t \mapsto x(t)$ is continuous, we find
   $$\|x(t_n) - x_0\| \to \|x(\bar t) - x_0\| = \inf_{t \ge 0}\|x(t)-x_0\|.$$
2. I think this is not possible. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ consider a spiral
   $$x(t) = (t^{-1} \, \sin(t^{-1}), t^{-1} \, \cos(t^{-1}))$$ and some $x_0$. Then, $\|x(t) - x_0\|$ alternates between increasing and decreasing on some subintervals.